# What and When needs to be cleaned up when using msgpack-c?

Tags: c++, memory-management, msgpack

I am using [Msgpack-c](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c). One thing that is not clear to me, is how to correctly handle memory when using this library. The quickstart examples declare everything locally and I presume rely on destructors being called when the application ends, but I cannot rely on the same.

Take the following:

```
    msgpack::unpacked msgunpacked;
    msgpack::unpack(&msgunpacked, msgdata, msglength);
    T params = msgunpacked.get().as<T>();
    return params ;
```

**When is it safe to delete `msgdata`?** After `unpack()`? After the conversion to `T`?

**When is it safe to delete `msgunpacked`?** After `get()`?

**Do I need to `delete` or `free` params?** And do I need to destroy members like `msgpack::type::raw_ref` explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When is it safe to delete msgdata? After unpack()? After the conversion to T?

When you use `msgpack::unpack()` function, the default unpacking behavior is **copy**. So you can destroy `msgdata` after `msgpack::unpack()` is called.

See [memory management](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_unpacker#memory-management)

You can customize the behavior of **copy**. When you pass `unpack_reference_func` handler to `msgpack::unpack()`, and when the handler returns **true**, `msgpack::unpacked` might refer to `msgdata`. You can check the reference status via `referenced` parameter. If the `reference` parameter is set to **true**, the `msgpack::unpacked` refers to `msgdata`.

```
void unpack(
    object_handle& result,
    const char* data,
    std::size_t len,
    bool& referenced, // actual status for reference
    unpack_reference_func f = nullptr, // customize copy/reference behavior
    void* user_data = nullptr,
    unpack_limit const& limit = unpack_limit());
```

Strictly speaking, `msgpack::unpacked` doesn't refer to `msgdata` directly, `msgpack::object` that is held by `msgpack::unpacked` refers to `msgdata`.

> When is it safe to delete msgunpacked? After get()?

See [accessing unpacked data](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_unpacker#accessing-unpacked-data)

`get()` is the member function for getting `msgpack::object`. The `msgpack::object` is located on `msgpack::zone`, a kind of memory pool. And  `msgpack::unpacked` contains `std::unique_ptr<msgpack::zone>`. That means you need to keep the lifetime of `msgunpacked` during you access the `msgpack::object` that is gotten by `get()`. If you convert to T from `msgpack::object`, and the T doesn't refer to `msgpack::object`, and you don't access `msgpack::object` any more, then you can destroy `msgunpacked`. I said that the T doesn't refer to `msgpack::object`. It depends on the type of T. Most of the types do not refer to `msgpack::object`. `msgpack::type::raw_ref`, `boost::string_ref`, and `msgpack::type::variant_ref` refer to `msgpack::object`.

If you convert to those types, you need to keep the lifetime of `msgpack::object`.

See [conversion](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_object#conversion) , [adaptor](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_adaptor) , [variant_ref](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/pull/349)

> Do I need to delete or free params?

No. T is located on the stack, you don't need to free it. If T contains the data on the heap like as `std::vector<sometype>`, the data should be freed by the destructor of the T.

> And do I need to destroy members like msgpack::type::raw_ref explicitly?

No, you don't need to free `msgpack::type::raw_ref`. It is just a reference type object. The memory that is referred by `msgpack::type::raw_ref` is freed when `msgunpacked` is freed.

Comment: That is brilliant. Thank you Takatoshi!